# How to press keyboard keys like Ctrl + S, Ctrl + A etc in Selenium?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

How to press <kbd>Ctrl + S</kbd> in Selenium Chrome Web Driver?

How to save PDF file in Selenium Chrome Web Driver?

Because its automatically opening in a new Chrome tab.

Comment: Don't use Selenium to save files, it's an anti pattern:http://ardesco.lazerycode.com/testing/webdriver/2012/07/25/how-to-download-files-with-selenium-and-why-you-shouldnt.html

Answer (score 1):

To click Ctrl+S, you can do it with Actions class

```
Actions actions=new Actions(driver);
actions.sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL+"S"))).build().perform();
```

Chord helps in simulating pressing many keys at once in.
Hope it helps !

Answer (score 0):

you have to use robot class for that.

1. import following jars:

   ```
   import java.awt.AWTException;   
   import java.awt.Robot;  
   import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
   ```
2. Press the keys you want to use:

   ```
   Robot robot = new Robot();
   robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
   robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_S);
   robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
   robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_S);
   robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
   robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
   ```
3. Keys event will be performed

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ActionBuilder` for this below code is in Python just for basic idea ..

```
driver.action.key_down(:control)
         .send_keys("s")
         .key_up(:control)
         .perform`
```